# How to check if the Firebase Stripe extension has finished creating the customer/user document?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I am using the [Firebase Stripe](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/stripe-firestore-stripe-payments) extension.

When a user is added to Firebase the Stripe extension uses Cloud Functions to create a `users` document in the Firestore Datastore.

In my app I have a function that creates a Firebase user, and then tries to update the matching `users` Firestore document.

But sometimes the Cloud Functions have not finished creating the `users` document and it returns this error:

```
No document to update: projects/APP_NAME/databases/(default)/documents/users/KHaY21FSUasdfOXFS123Kfge85VA3
```

To get around this problem I am using a `timeout` that pauses for a few seconds before proceeding. It's not an ideal solution.

Instead, I want to know if the Firebase Stripe extension has finished creating the `users` doc before proceeding.

How can that be done?

Here is my app function:

```TypeScript
export const useCreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordTask = () => {
  const updateDocTask = useUpdateDocTask();
  return useTask(function* (
    signal,
    email: string,
    password: string,
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
  ) {
    // Create the user in Firebase
    // The Firebase Stripe extension will now use Cloud Functions to also create a 'users' doc with related user info
    const userCredential: UserCredential = yield createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      auth,
      email,
      password
    );
    // Now I wait 3 seconds to make sure the 'users' doc is created before updating it.
    // Without this timeout it will occasionally throw an error because updateDocTask is called before the 'users' doc is created
    // Is there a better way of doing this?
    yield timeout(3000);
    const updateDoc: void = yield updateDocTask.perform(
      'users',
      userCredential.user.uid,
      {
        firstName: firstName,
        lastName: lastName,
        createdAt: timestamp,
      }
    );
    return Promise.all([userCredential, updateDoc]);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [realtime listeners](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) instead of `setTimeout()` as shown below:

```
import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const unsub = onSnapshot(doc(db, "users", "<USER_DOC_ID>"), (doc) => {
    // This function triggers whenever the document is created/updated/deleted
    console.log("Data: ", doc.data());
});
```

Do check if `doc.data()` has data already just in case the extension has added document before user reaches this page.

Comment: Thanks this worked. I wrapped it in a `yield new Promise((resolve) => { // your code here }` so that it would wait until resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
db.doc("/{path to doc}").set(data, {
  merge: true,
})
```

then you don't have to wait for it to be created. This should merge with the document created by Stripe. I have been doing this for all my projects and it has worked well.